# Fingerprint Reader in OpenERP7

Tags: java, python, web-services, odoo, fingerprint

I have the need to integrate the fingerprint reader 'U.are.U 4500 Fingerprint Reader' to OpenERP 7. I have an idea of ​​how to do it and I would like to share with you and get their feedback to determine if it is a good way.

1. The first thing would be to develop in java (Reader API available)
   one kind of 'http server' which answers requests for certain port
   and run the capture, verification, validation of the trace requests
   and answer a code status and other information such as the bytes of
   the fingerprint.
2. From OpenERP used that could consume web services that application
   done in java and thus make communication with the fingerprint reader
   if need applets and weird stuff.

You think of this way to communicate OpenERP with a fingerprint reader?

Comment: Not sure, how openerp can be directly associated with this ? OpenERP can consume the end result which can be an "Attendance Log" of a person and can do other computational stuff.

Comment: @Parthiv, I do not understand what you mean, I'm trying to find the best way to communicate the fingerprint reader and architecture of OpenERP webservice.